# Simple JQuery Accordion menu: open second by default

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-accordion

I am using a simple jquery accordian menu.  But I want the second item in the list to be open by default rather than the :first

How can this be done?

```
function initMenu()
{
     $('#menu ul').hide();
     $('#menu ul:first').show();
     $('#menu li a').click(function()
     {
          var checkElement = $(this).next();
          if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (checkElement.is(':visible')))
          {
               return false;
          }
          if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible')))
          {
               $('#menu ul:visible').slideUp('normal');
               checkElement.slideDown('normal');
               return false;
          }
     });
}
$(document).ready(function() {initMenu();});
```

I am also wondering if I could use a selected class to help make this more dynamic:

> ```
> <div id="work_menu">
>      <ul id="side_menu" class="nav_categories">    
>          <li>
>              <a href="celebratory-use">Celebratory Use</a>
>              <ul>
>                  <li><a  href="platters">Platters</a></li>
>                  <li><a  href="celebratory-servers">Servers</a></li>
>              </ul>
>          </li>
>          <li><a  class="selected" href="daily-use">Daily Use</a>
>             <ul>
>             <li><a  href="bowls">Bowls</a></li>
>             <li><a  href="butter-dishes">Butter Dishes</a></li>
>             <li><a  href="mugs">Mugs</a></li>
>             </ul>
>
>         </li>      </ul> </div>
> ```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/eastwooddesign/FbtMj/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `$('#menu ul:eq(1)').show();` instead of `$('#menu ul:first').show();`, this would apply `.show()` to the second element `ul` element in `#menu`. Without the HTML it is difficult to see if this is the proper solution.

To make it so that the `ul` coming after the item given the `.selected` class is shown, change `$('#menu ul:eq(1)').show();` to `$('#side_menu li > a.selected + ul').show();`, so long as the `.selected` class is always applied to an `<a>`. If you wish to apply it to another sibling element of the `<li>`, then change the selector to `$('#side_menu li .selected + ul').show();`, which is a little more generalizable.

Comment: that actually works, but in order to make the menu a bit more dynamic is there a way to use a selected class and make that ul show? see updated html code above

Comment: @PeterEastwood Please see the changes I made to my answer.